# How to insert data in database using web-service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2017

I am making a web-service to insert data in database in asp.net c# and VS-2017
and after running my web-service and on click of invoke button it gives error:
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
[WebMethod]
public int InsertClients(string sClientName, int nShippingId, string sEmailId, string sMemoMail, string sClientCode)
{
    int retRecord = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ClientDetails", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("sClientName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sClientName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("nShippingId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = nShippingId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("sEmailId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sEmailId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("sMemoMail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sMemoMail;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("sClientCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sClientCode;
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            retRecord = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return retRecord;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct URL? What URL are you using?

Comment: Have you added web reference to this service in your client program? Have you updated the URL to reflect where the service is hosted in your client program?

Comment: @nick this is my URL : http://localhost:48323/AddClientDetails.asmx/InsertClients    where AddClientDetails is a class & InsertClients is my Method.

Comment: @himanshu i am totally new to this , can you guide me pls through the process.

Comment: Insert-clients is the correct spelling? I guess - is not allowed _ would come

Comment: Method signature is invalid, how it's name contains - sign in it `Insert-Clients`, how it is even compiled??

Comment: @hammad while updating in STACK-OVERFLOW i bymistakely did that, my code is proper, thank you.

Comment: @vishu_tech, As you mentioned your functionality is not able to call that web-service and error shows that Resource not found, I suggest you to use fiddler or anyother web-service tester, so that you able to found that the path you are providing of the web-service is correct or wrong. Reference: https://apitester.com/

Comment: As your webservice seems offline, use windows tools, or some browser extension to test the webservice first.